# Show X-Frame-Options: header in asp.net development server

Tags: asp.net, http-headers, x-frame-options

When I run my application in Windows Azure I can see the `X-Frame-Options` in the header. When I run it in the asp.net development server (on localhost), I am not able to view that header.

How can I make the application include the `X-Frame-Options` header while it is running in the asp.net development server (on localhost)?

```
Azure output:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
**X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN**
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 01 Dec 2014 08:37:30 GMT
Content-Length: 2039
```

Local dev server output:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/11.0.0.0
Date: Mon, 01 Dec 2014 09:28:08 GMT
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 622
Connection: Close
```

Comment: Why do you actually need it on your dev server?

Comment: I need to make some changes to the setting and want to make sure it has worked before deploying to Azure

Comment: Pretty sure you can just add that programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set headers in IIS you need the IIS manager: in the tree select your web application and the open the "HTTP Response Headers" control.

Or, you could, add the header to the [`Response.Headers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.headers%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) collection in your code.

Comment: but can you see this in the development server that runs when visual studio is debugging your code? I don't want to deploy locally to iis either. I just want the output when I am using the debugger

Comment: Which "development server": IIS Express or Casini? For IIS Express it can probably be done in its confirmation file, for Casini I expect you're out of luck.

Comment: thanks. it shows when I run it in iis express rather than casini